# Hide and Show - slideToggle with fadeIn

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, slidetoggle

I have a menu with three links, linkOne, LinkTwo, linkThree.

linkOne: I put a slideToggle on. and it works like i want, when i press its open it and when i press again it closes, this is what I'm after.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.linkOne').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.linkTwo-content').hide();  
    $('.linkThree-content').hide();  
    $('.linkOne-content').slideToggle(500);      
    return false;  
  });
```

linkTwo: here I put a fadeIn that also works on this effect.

```
$('.linkTwo').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.linkThree-content').hide();      
    $('.linkOne-content').hide();      
    $('.linkTwo-content').fadeIn(500);         
    return false;
  });
```

linkThree: I did the same here as in linkTwo.

```
    $('.linkThree').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.linkOne-content').hide();      
    $('.linkTwo-content').hide();      
    $('.linkThree-content').fadeIn(500);         
    return false;
  });

});
```

The thing I want to do is to add the effect FadeIn that I use in linkTwo and linkThreer to LinkOne so it become a slideToggle that fadeIn when it¨s open and fadeOuts with the slideToggle when it closes. Then I want all three links to do this and have this effect, slideToggleFadeIn.

I don't want you to change the code to much cause I want to understand whats happens in it. So if you can help please don't just put a fresh code to it.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lamberta/Pkdj5/

Answer (score 0):

I would update your code so there is not so much redundancy; it should be pretty easy to use one function bound to each of the links that shows/hides as appropriate.  I've gotten you started here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pkdj5/2/

`.slideToggle` is changed to `.css('opacity' 0).animate({'opacity': 1, 'height', 'show'})` in order to create the simultaneous fade/slide effect.  You can also use the `'toggle'` values for opacity and height if you want to use only one `animate`.

Comment: Sorry, something is not right there in the your code if you compare to the one i posted, that works correct (without the effects i want). When i press linkOne, yes it slides down one time but without the fadeIn i want. Then when you press it again it dosent close it and slideUp, it just starts to fade everytime you press linkOne.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Pkdj5/11/

JavaScript:

```
if(!$('.linkOne-content').is(":visible")){
     $('.linkOne-content').fadeIn(500);
     $('.linkOne-content p').slideDown(500);
}
else{
     $('.linkOne-content').fadeOut(500);
     $('.linkOne-content p').slideUp(500);
}
```

css:

```
p {display: block}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but in your event listener callback for the click event on your elements you could write:

```
$('.yourels').on('click', function(e){
    $(e.target).slideToggle({
        progress : function(ani, now){
            $(e.target).css('opacity', now);
        }
    });
})
```

Neat part here is that the now prop goes from 0 to 1 just like opacity